# How unique is socket id created by Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Every socket is given a unique id, which can be used to look up that socket and emit to it.

It's a piece of string, but how unique is it? Is collision possible within multiple socket.io objects running with a cluster module, without synchronization? Can the id be changed if collision is detected? Can I change the length of the key or the algorithm generating it, so that the ids are seeded using unique value for each process (i.e. process id)?

Comment: They are local to the host they are created on.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But are they using a common generation algorithm, so that two servers in the room will generate the same id for two socket connections, assuming everything is identical for both connections?